# django filter data and make union of all data points to assignt to a new data

Tags: django

My model is as follows

```
class Drawing(models.Model):
    drawingJSONText = models.TextField(null=True)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Sample data saved in drawingJSONText field is as below

```
{"points":[{"x":109,"y":286,"r":1,"color":"black"},{"x":108,"y":285,"r":1,"color":"black"},{"x":106,"y":282,"r":1,"color":"black"},{"x":103,"y":276,"r":1,"color":"black"},],"lines":[{"x1":109,"y1":286,"x2":108,"y2":285,"strokeWidth":"2","strokeColor":"black"},{"x1":108,"y1":285,"x2":106,"y2":282,"strokeWidth":"2","strokeColor":"black"},{"x1":106,"y1":282,"x2":103,"y2":276,"strokeWidth":"2","strokeColor":"black"}]}
```

I am trying to write a view file where the data is filtered based on project field and all the resulting queryset of drawingJSONText field are made into one data

```
def load(request):
    """ Function to load the drawing with drawingID if it exists."""
    try:
        filterdata = Drawing.objects.filter(project=1)
        ids = filterdata.values_list('pk', flat=True)
        length = len(ids)
        print(list[ids])
        print(len(list(ids)))

        drawingJSONData = dict()
        drawingJSONData = {'points': [], 'lines': []}

        for val in ids:
            if length >= 0:
                continue
                drawingJSONData1 = json.loads(Drawing.objects.get(id=ids[val]).drawingJSONText)
                drawingJSONData["points"] = drawingJSONData1["points"] + drawingJSONData["points"]
                drawingJSONData["lines"] = drawingJSONData1["lines"] + drawingJSONData["lines"]
            length -= 1
        #print(drawingJSONData)
        drawingJSONData = json.dumps(drawingJSONData)
        context = {
            "loadIntoJavascript": True,
            "JSONData": drawingJSONData
        }
        # Editing response headers and returning the same
        response = modifiedResponseHeaders(render(request, 'MainCanvas/index.html', context))
        return response
```

I runs without error but it shows a blank screen
i dont think the for function is working
any suggestions on how to rectify

Comment: I think you may have several issues, but I'm not clear on your loop and the purpose of length and continue. It looks like you end the loop everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I **think** you may want

```
for id_val in ids:
    drawingJSONData1 = json.loads(Drawing.objects.get(id=id_val).drawingJSONText)
    drawingJSONData["points"] = drawingJSONData1["points"] + drawingJSONData["points"]
    drawingJSONData["lines"] = drawingJSONData1["lines"] + drawingJSONData["lines"]
```